# Can we give a bound on any associative function?

Tags: functions, asymptotics, associativity

We say that $f:[1,\infty)^2\to[1,\infty)$ is associative if $$f(f(a,b),c)=f(a,f(b,c))$$
And symmetric if $$f(a,b)=f(b,a)$$

e.g. the arithmetic operations '+' and '$\cdot$' are associative and symmetric.

> **Can we give a bound $b:[1,\infty)^2\to[1,\infty)$ (which might not be associative) such that every associative function $f$ satisfies $$\exists c\:\forall x,y\in [1,\infty): f(x,y)\leq c\cdot b(x,y)$$**

,

> **If not, can we find such bound on every associative and symmetric function?**

Answer (score 1):

Proffering the following argument aiming to prove that no such function $b$ can exist.

Assume contariwise that such a function $b$ exists.

Let $D$ be a set of representatives of cosets of the (multiplicative) subgroup $\Bbb{Q}^*_{>0}$ of $\Bbb{R}^*_{>0}$. Note that if $d\in D$ we can always replace $d$ by $10d$, if we so desire. So without loss of generality we can assume that $D\subset [1,\infty).$
Because $D$ is uncountable, we can set a side a countably infinite subset
$$
N=\{d_0,d_1,d_2,\ldots\}\subseteq D.
$$
We then replace $D$ with the set
$$
D_b=(D\setminus N)\cup\{d_i10^{k_i}\mid i\in\Bbb{N}\},
$$
where the exponents $k_i$ are integers selected in such a way that $$d_i10^{k_i}>10^ib(1,d_i)$$
for all $i\in\Bbb{N}$. Observe that $D_b$ is still a set of representatives of cosets.

Given such a set $D_b$ we define a function
$f:[1,\infty)\times[1,\infty)\to D_b$ by declaring that $f(a,b)=d\in D_b$  where $d$ is the unique number in $D$ belonging to the coset of $ab$. This function is both associative and symmetric, because 
$f(f(a,b),c)$ and $f(a,f(b,c))$ are both equal to the uniquely determined $d\in D_b$ with the property that $abc$ is a rational multiple of $d$.

For any natural number $n$ we then also have
$$
f(1,d_n)=10^{k_n}d_n>10^nb(1,d_n).
$$
This means that no constant $c$ will work for this particular choice of an associative $f$, because $10^n>c$ for some choice of $n$.

So essentially I took the multiplication, but I replaced the correct product with its more or less arbitrary rational multiple. Or, the ratio $f(a,b)/ab$ is always a rational number. The key is that by selecting the multiples carefully we won't break associativity.

Mind you, this argument may depend on the Axiom of Choice. Otherwise sets like $D$ may not exist.

---

A less general but easier to follow attempt at construction is to use suitable bijections to port an associative algebraic structure. Let $\phi:[1,\infty)\to[1,\infty)$ be any bijection. Then the function
$$
f(a,b)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(a)\cdot\phi(b))
$$
is easily seen to be associative, because both $f(f(a,b),c))$ and $f(a,f(b,c))$ are equal
to $\phi^{-1}(\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(c))$.

Consider the following function $\phi:[1,\infty)\to[1,\infty)$
$$
\phi(x)=
\begin{cases}
10^n,&\quad\text{if $x=2^n$ for some natural number $n$,}\\
2^n,&\quad\text{if $x=10^n$ for some natural number $n$,}\\
x,&\quad\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
So if $n$ is an odd natural number and $a=b=2^{n/2}$, we get
$$
f(a,b)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(a)\phi(b))=
\phi^{-1}(2^{n/2}\cdot2^{n/2})=\phi^{-1}(2^n)=10^n.
$$
So for these values of $a,b$ we get $f(a,b)=5^nab$ where we can choose
$n$ to be any odd natural number (so arbitrarily large). This is a counterexample to
many a bound $b(x,y)$, for example to the bound $b(x,y)=(x+y)^2$ the OP asked about in a comment.

Comment: I hope there is a simpler argument out there :-)

Comment: Hmm. A second reading of the question reveals to me that the constant $c$ may depend on the function $f$. I need to think about an appropriate way of tweaking the end game...

Comment: Fixed now, I think.

Comment: I really hope there is a simpler argument, because I wasn't able to follow this one :(.

Comment: Can you perhaps give an example of the resulting associative function $f$ by your construction that makes the $b(x,y)=(x+y)^2$ bound fail?

Comment: @RB: I am using AoC. There is no concrete description of the set $D$. This is an existence proof. Not a construction.

Comment: @RB: I added another potentially useful method for constructing associative functions. That is hopefully easier to follow. But it isn't as universal as the other one. May be that method can also be made to work for all $b$?

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is much better :).

Comment: I'm wondering now if it's possible to bound all the *continuous* associative functions. Both your (And Somu's) constructions disproved it using non-continuous $f$. Perhaps this is true otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

There exists no such $b$ even if $f$ is symmetric and associative.Let $f(x,y)$ be defined by $$f(x,y)=[(b(x,y)+b(y,x)+1).e^{x+y}]+1.1$$ where $[.]$ is greatest integer function if both $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers and $f(x,y)=1.1$ if any one of $x$,$y$ fail to be a natural number.Notice that $f(f(x,y),z)=f(x,f(y,z))=1.1$ for all $x,y,z$ since $f(x,y)$ is always not a natural number.It is easy to see that $f$ is symmetric.There exists no $c$ such that $f(x,y)/b(x,y)\leq c \forall x,y$ since $f(n,n)/b(n,n)$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Can you please explain why your $f$ is associative?

Comment: I edited my answer $f$ was not associative last time.

Comment: Looks good. Do you think it can be strengthen to continuous functions $f$? (your solution seems to heavily rely on the fact $f(f(\cdot))$ is going down to $1.1$.

Comment: I can extend this result to the continuous case.I constructed a continuous function $f$ satisfying the properties which is symmetric and $$f(x,y)=[(b(x,y)+b(y,x)+1).e^{x+y}]+1.1$$ if $x$ and $y$ are integers and $$f(x,y)=1.1$$ if any of $x$ or $y$ have fractional part equal to 0.1.But the expression for $f$ is messy.It should be clear that $f$ satisfying these properties is associative and $f(x,y)/b(x,y)$ is unbounded.

Comment: Sorry the continuous function I constructed fails to be associative.Making a function satisfy the associative property seems to be a big problem.I can fix the errors but I will need some time.